# Is there a vegan or vegetarian instant noodles?

Tags: veganism, substitutes, vegetarian-diet, is-it-vegetarian

In Australia, but don't mind global suggestions. I have tried looking for some good noodles that are decent and are on the hot and spicy side of the flavour scale.

Comment: Instant noodles are an empty calorie food. It's better to just microwave any kind of noodle for 2-3 minutes, stir, and 1-2 minutes more with extra-virgin olive oil and iodized salt. I usually do elbow macaroni for 3 min, stir, 2 more min (if I'm too lazy to boil a bigger batch with 3-5 servings for 9-11 minutes).

Answer (score 3):

I personally think most instant noodles are not very nutritious and full of flavour enhancers etc god knows what else.

Here is an alternative approach that I take, and it will allow you more control of what is in your food.

So instead of instant noodles, I will buy various plain noodles like [this](https://shop.countdown.co.nz/shop/productdetails?stockcode=40313&name=erawan-asian-rice-sticks-medium), or [Asian vermicelli](https://shop.countdown.co.nz/shop/productdetails?stockcode=17568&name=double-phoenix-asian-vermicelli-green-bean) or this [very high protein bean noodles](https://shop.countdown.co.nz/shop/productdetails?stockcode=111675&name=trident-black-bean-noodles-organic), and combine a sauce flavouring containing natural ingredients like [this](https://shop.countdown.co.nz/shop/productdetails?stockcode=784117&name=exotic-food-asian-tom-yum-soup-paste) or miso paste, and maybe add veges (mushroom, spring onion) or herb garnishes. Takes maybe 5 minutes instead of 2 minutes. Costs $2 instead of 50c.

I am in NZ but I assume you can get the same items from Wooleys (its called Countdown here).

Comment: A valid alternative, but  4x the price, less available, and less portable means it won't be for everyone.  I also prefer to cook properly but instant noodles only need a source of boiling water. Even the ones that say they should be boiled or microwaved can just be prepared by soaking in hot water

Comment: Good call. Another DIY version I did recently which is less gourmet, cheaper and more portable (and soakable):  In a zip lock bag: put a plain dry noodle that can cook via soaking, (e.g. thin rice vermicelli), a foil wrapped stock cube (e.g. Rapunzel organic stock powder or cube), and a small amount of freeze dried mix veges (the kind you get in the camping stores). Can also add TVP for protein that easily cooks via soaking. Can also add more salt to taste, as well as dried chives, and chilli powder, spice etc.

Comment: That 2nd alternative is getting close to what I take camping, though I also use home-dried home-grown veg.  Spotting a tin of pre-cooked lentils in a campsite shop made for a nice change too (drain, pour over boiling water)

Answer (score 3):

### Sri Lanka

Kottu Mee Hot and Spicy Instant Noodles are my favorite. I usually bring back about fifty packages when I return to Canada

[image]

I also love the Cheese and Onion flavor which I find just as spicy.

[image]

They cost about fifty cents a package.

The package of the cheese flavor states 'May contain traces of Milk Products', but at least there are no chunks of meat.

Answer (score 3):

I have little trouble finding vegetarian ones in the UK.  As an example I have to hand, the "curry flavour" Maggi* ones list no animal-derived ingredients.  Milk is listed as an allergen that may be contained, rather than as an ingredient.

Unfortunately the rather tasty Indo-Mie vegetable flavour (with chilli and lime) ones are suspect.  They contain [E631 disodium inosinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disodium_inosinate) as a flavour enhancer, which may be animal-derived if not specified. They also "may contain" egg as a potential allergen.

---

* Maggi is a Nestle brand, and one you have to check carefully.  They do strange things like adding cow's milk derivatives to coconut milk powder.  They tend to be available in many countries, but not always to the same recipe.